# Web scraping data table with python Selenium, BeautifulSoup and Pandas failed

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape/extract the table in the following website using python. (This is a dynamic table, so i cant just save the html in an html file, since it will get updated every so often).
https://www.eib.org/en/about/procurement/index.htm

My goal is to turn the table into a dataframe.
I used:

1. Selenium and BeautifulSoup, which both return an empty list
2. Pandas with pd.read_html which returns "no tables found" error

Any ideas why this is happening? And how can i fix this?

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL='http://www.eib.org/en/about/procurement/index.htm'
driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path ='/Users/***********')
driver.get(URL)
r=requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
page = driver.page_source
page_soup = soup(page,'html.parser')

#Using beautiful soup
elements=soup.findAll("tr")
print(elements)
for e in elements:
    dr=e.find("td")
    print(dr.text)

#Using selenium
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td")
for elem in elems:
    e=elem.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
    print(e.tex)

#Using pandas
pd.read_html(URL)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the url that actually has the table in the response. Can find this by searching the Network tab in the Dev Tools:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.eib.org/tools/jsp/calls.jsp?&lang=en&language=en&l=en&url=/about/procurement/index.htm&forceLanguage=en&_=1616778335822'
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
           Date                                              Title     Status
0    26/03/2021  Education Buildings in Ireland â€” Energy Effi...  OnÂ going
1    18/03/2021  Public Procurement Expertise and Support to ov...     Closed
2    18/03/2021  Advisory Support to Project Advisory Support U...     Closed
3    17/03/2021  Advanced Case Management System (e-CMS) for th...     Closed
4    16/03/2021  Technical Assistance to Support the Implementa...  OnÂ going
..          ...                                                ...        ...
524  01/09/2005  Maintenance contract for the EIB's parkland an...     Closed
525  05/08/2005                 Cleaning services for EIB premises     Closed
526  15/07/2005  Network maintenance engineering and acquisitio...     Closed
527  13/07/2005                      Contract relating to removals     Closed
528  09/07/2003  Extension of call for tenders for translation/...     Closed

[529 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: omg thank you so much. I've been stuck for 5 hours!!

Comment: Should have also worked with selenium too. Issue was youI weren’t using it really at all. You used selenium to get the html, but then used requests. Essentially selenium wasn’t used for anything in your code except to go to a page,  or to parse it. I’ll add that solution to this tomorrow so you can see how that works, but imho, this way is more efficient.

Comment: This has already been extremely helpful. Thanks to this, I was able to extract the data, clean it, use it, etc! My only question is : Will this URL that contains the table need to be updated every so often or can I just keep using the same link in the future? Thanks again 

Comment: I’m not sure. It could be dynamic but not sure. I’ll look into it tomorrow and see if I can find if it’s a static url.

Comment: I tried and remove that last parameter of `1616778335822` and I still got the response. So it appears to be ok and should be fine

Comment: Thank you infinitely for your time  !  you've been a huge help